# Z3_mk_config and Z3_mk_context deprecated (Z3 C API). Which functions should we use now?

Tags: c, z3

I'm using the C API of Z3. I've checked the examples, and Z3_mk_config() and Z3_mk_context (Z3_config c)    are used to create contexts, e.g.,

```
Z3_config  cfg;
Z3_context ctx;
cfg = Z3_mk_config();
Z3_set_param_value(cfg, "model", "true");
//...
ctx = Z3_mk_context(cfg);
```

However, the documentation says that all these functions are deprecated, but don't mention which functions should be used now instead.

Does anyone know which functions should be used now to create configurations and contexts?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you look into `Z3` sources, there is a remark in `Z3_mk_config()` description: "In previous versions of `Z3`, the `Z3_config` was used to store global and module configurations. Now, we should use `Z3_global_param_set`". It seems the reason why all `Z3 API` functions that works with `Z3_config` are deprecated now. Use `Z3_global_param_set` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I saw that, but mk_context and mk_context_rc both require an argument of type Z3_config. How can I get such an argument then?

Comment: Apparently you should use `Z3_global_param_set` function. Here is from its description: "Set a global (or module) parameter. This setting is shared by all `Z3` contexts. When a `Z3` module is initialized it will use the value of these parameters when `Z3_params` objects are not provided. ... This function can be used to set parameters for a specific `Z3` module."

Comment: Right, I can use `Z3_global_param_set` to set global parameters, but I still need an object of type `Z3_config` to create a context (either with `Z3_mk_context` or `Z3_mk_context_rc`, both require an argument of type `Z3_config`). That was my point above... `Z3_global_param_set` does not return an object of type `Z3_config`, so I don't see a way to create a context without the old `Z3_mk_config`...

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

- Use `Z3_mk_config` to create a `Z3_config`.
- Use `Z3_global_param_set` to set configs globally.
- Use `Z3_set_param_value` to set context-specific configs.
- If you don't have any config to set, simply

  1. make a `Z3_config` with `Z3_mk_config`,
  2. create your context with it,
  3. and then delete it with `Z3_del_config`.

---

The comment by SergeyLebedev is probably referencing to this remark in the [doc](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga893d6f1df01056553b7ca1ba3a4e848c)

> In previous versions of Z3, the `Z3_config` was used to store global and
>   module configurations. Now, we should use `Z3_global_param_set`.

I was going through the source repo the past few days. In the example file `test_capi.c`, they use this `mk_context` function a lot, which is defined in the same file with

```cpp
Z3_context mk_context()
{
    Z3_config  cfg;
    Z3_context ctx;
    cfg = Z3_mk_config();
    ctx = mk_context_custom(cfg, error_handler);
    Z3_del_config(cfg);
    return ctx;
}
```

where `mk_context_custom` is defined in the same file with

```cpp
Z3_context mk_context_custom(Z3_config cfg, Z3_error_handler err)
{
    Z3_context ctx;

    Z3_set_param_value(cfg, "model", "true");
    ctx = Z3_mk_context(cfg);
    Z3_set_error_handler(ctx, err);

    return ctx;
}
```

So it looks like `Z3_mk_config` and `Z3_set_param_value` are still used.

The doc says that stuff like `Z3_config` and `Z3_context` are supposed to be "opaque pointers". However, chasing it to the source, it looks like `Z3_config` is declared as a struct without the specific content but seems like wherever it's used it's cast to `context_params` which is defined clearly as a class.

The type `Z3_config` is declared in `z3_api_h` with

```cpp
DEFINE_TYPE(Z3_config);
```

where `DEFINE_TYPE(T)` is a macro defined in `z3_macros.h` and expands to `typedef struct _ ## T *T`. So really `Z3_config` is only prototypically declared as a struct.

The function `Z3_mk_config`, the constructor for a `Z3_config`, declared in `z3_api.h` with

```cpp
Z3_config Z3_API Z3_mk_config(void);
```

, is defined in `api_config_params.cpp` as

```cpp
Z3_config Z3_API Z3_mk_config(void) {
    try {
        memory::initialize(UINT_MAX);
        LOG_Z3_mk_config();
        Z3_config r = reinterpret_cast<Z3_config>(alloc(context_params));
        RETURN_Z3(r);
    } catch (z3_exception & ex) {
        // The error handler is only available for contexts
        // Just throw a warning.
        warning_msg("%s", ex.msg());
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

within an `extern "C"` block. Note that `Z3_API` is a macro also defined in `z3_macros.h` to set `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` and `alloc` is a macro defined in `memory_manager.h` with `#define alloc(T,...) new (memory::allocate(sizeof(T))) T(__VA_ARGS__)` and `RETURN_Z3` is a macro defined in some file generated by the file `update_api.py` with `#define RETURN_Z3(Z3RES) if (_LOG_CTX.enabled()) { SetR(Z3RES); } return Z3RES`.

It appears that, when a `Z3_config` is created, a memory block of the size of a `context_params` is allocated and cast as `Z3_config`, and `context_params` is in fact a class defined clearly in `context_params.h`. I omit the content because it's not relevant right now.

```cpp
class context_params {
    ....
};
```

Next, `Z3_set_param_value` is defined in `api_config_params.cpp` with

```cpp
void Z3_API Z3_set_param_value(Z3_config c, char const * param_id, char const * param_value) {
    LOG_Z3_set_param_value(c, param_id, param_value);
    try {
        context_params * p = reinterpret_cast<context_params*>(c);
        p->set(param_id, param_value);
    }
    catch (z3_exception & ex) {
        // The error handler is only available for contexts
        // Just throw a warning.
        warning_msg("%s", ex.msg());
    }
}
```

So it appears that the function first cast `Z3_config` back to `context_params` before using it like a normal object. I'm not an expert but this probably works because [struct and class are almost the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939609/how-is-the-memory-layout-of-a-class-vs-a-struct) underneath the hood.

On the other hand, in that exmaple file `test_capi.c`, they used `Z3_global_param_set` like so

```cpp
....
cfg = Z3_mk_config();
....
/*
   The current model finder for quantified formulas cannot handle injectivity.
   So, we are limiting the number of iterations to avoid a long "wait".
*/
Z3_global_param_set("smt.mbqi.max_iterations", "10");
ctx = mk_context_custom(cfg, error_handler);
Z3_del_config(cfg);
s = mk_solver(ctx);
```

They did still use `Z3_mk_config` before making a context while using `Z3_global_param_set` to set configs. So I'd say there's nothing wrong with using `Z3_mk_config` to construct a `Z3_config`, and what the doc is saying is when you want to set something globally, don't access the `Z3_config` struct itself since you can't before casting it to a `context_params` anyway; use `Z3_global_param_set` instead. And when you want to set something specific to some specific context, use `Z3_set_param_value`.

---

The question remains that why would we want to switch between structs and classes? I don't know. I'm not at all familiar with C++, but I'm guessing, if not for the C API itself, it's for making the `extern "C"` part works [for the Python API bindings](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#writing-extensions-in-c).